# Hibernate @OneToMany empty set

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

Tell me correctly I understand that when you call getOrders(), must return full Set?

FK in Orders Table.

Or you just need to use HQL(JPQL) to get Orders object?

I'm getting empty set.
When i call getter Set orderSet = bid.getOrders(); in debug i dont show any actions.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bid") 
public class Bid {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "bid_id",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Order> orders = new HashSet<>();
@Column(name = "title")
private String title;
@Column(name = "description")
private String description;


public Set<Order> getOrders() {
    return orders;
}

public void setOrders(Set<Order> orders) {
    this.orders = orders;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;
@Column(name = "title")
private String title;

@ManyToOne(optional = true,fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = 
CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "bid")
private Bid bid_id;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class BidDao {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

public void create(Bid bid){
    entityManager.persist(bid);
}
```

}

Comment: Yes,it should return full set.Pls show how you get Bit in dao level?

Comment: mmm, in dao i doing create only , but getter call in controller Set<Order> orderSet = bid.getOrders();

Comment: Create/Read/Update/Delete operations on the `Entity` should be  in the `Repository`, not in the `Controller`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

- from One to Many side

  ```
  @OneToMany (targetEntity = Order.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)

  @JoinColumn (name = "order_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
  ```
- From Many to one side

  ```
  @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Bid.class, optional = true,fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade =
          CascadeType.ALL)

  @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
  ```